# ERROR while connecting JDBC

Tags: jdbc

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Jdbcdemo {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc.oracle:thin:@hp-hp:1521:xe","system", "ashu41228");
            if(c!=null)
            {
                System.out.println("DataBase is Created");


            }


        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc.oracle:thin:@hp-hp:1521:xe
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at Jdbcdemo.main(Jdbcdemo.java:12)

the above exception is coming i dont know how to tackle this.pls help

Answer (score 1):

According to the stacktrace,

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found

It looks like you don't have suitable driver for Oracle database.
To solve this problem, you'll have to have Oracle JDBC driver in your classpath.

You can download suitable driver from [oracle site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html) and add the package to your build path.

Refer to [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html) to set your classpath or other SO questions.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're getting does not necessarily mean you don't have the right driver or that you don't have a driver in your classpath. I think you must have a driver in your classpath because the `Class.forName` call succeeded. According to the [FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC) you should be loading "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", but you're finding something and that's a good sign.

Your JDBC url should start with `jdbc:oracle:thin:` (not `jdbc.oracle:thin:`). Even if everything else is right, getting the prefix wrong will cause the "No suitable driver found" error to occur (I verified this with the Oracle jars in my classpath and a JDBC url that I know works):

```
groovy:000> url = "jdbc.oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/FOOBAR"
groovy:000> DriverManager.getConnection(url, "asdf", "zxcv")
ERROR java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc.oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/FOOBAR
        at java_sql_DriverManager$getConnection.call (Unknown Source)
        at groovysh_evaluate.run (groovysh_evaluate:4)
        ...
```

Once you get the prefix right then if the rest of the url has a problem you will get a different error:

```
groovy:000> url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/FOOBAR"
groovy:000> DriverManager.getConnection(url, "asdf", "asdf")
ERROR java.sql.SQLRecoverableException:
IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon (T4CConnection.java:419)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init> (PhysicalConnection.java
:536)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init> (T4CConnection.java:228)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection (T4CDriverExtensi
on.java:32)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect (OracleDriver.java:521)
        at java_sql_DriverManager$getConnection.call (Unknown Source)
        at groovysh_evaluate.run (groovysh_evaluate:4)
        ...
```

Usually the url is something like

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//dbserver:port/databasename
```

Check with your DBA to find out what the right url should be.